# Fresh install of monit 5.24 can't run basic parameters from the command line

Tags: centos, monit

I just compiled the latest (as of Sep 2017) version of monit. It seems to function and deliver data to my mmonit server.

I'm using Linux/Centos 2.6.32-042stab094.7 #1 SMP Wed Oct 22 12:43:21 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

However, if I simply want to run the most basic command line arguments, they all seem to fail, e.g.:

```
$ monit -V; monit status

This is Monit version 5.24.0
Built with ssl, with ipv6, with compression, with pam and with large files
Copyright (C) 2001-2017 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
```

There is no service named "_status"

Or another example:

```
$ monit validate
Monit daemon with PID 7801 awakened
There is no service named "_status"
```

==========

Compared to another server I have:

```
$ monit -V; monit status
This is Monit version 5.6
Copyright (C) 2001-2013 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
The Monit daemon 5.6 uptime: 5h 4m
```

System 'example.com'
  status                            Running
[... followed by a summary of all services]

It seems as though all CLI arguments preceded by (dash) - work, such as:

```
monit -V
monit -t
```

But anything without a dash fails (status, restart, stop, summary)

Any such parameter results with:

There is no service named "_summary"

Answer (score 0):

Stand down! Solved it.

The prior monit daemon was running. Though I compiled, installed and ran the new monit, I never killed the old process!

Figured someone else might run into the issue so I won't delete the question.